# Group an array of objects based on multi keys in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, arraylist

I would like to share with you an existence problem

I have array as follows

```
const data = [
 {
   "countries": ["France", "USA", "Canada"],
   "city": "Paris",
   "stadium": "Parce de france"
 },
 {
   "countries": ["France", "Itlay", "Spain"],
   "city": "Roma",
   "arena": "La cigal"
 },
  {
   "countries": ["France"],
   "city": "Roma",
   "stadium": "Olymico"
 },
 {
   "countries": ["France"],
   "city": "Paris",
   "arena": "Velodrome"
 },
]
```

I want to group it first by city then by stadium and arena if exist
How can I achieve this

output like :

```
 {
   "city": "Paris",
   "arena": [
     {
       "value":"Velodrome",
       "countries": ["France"]
     }
   ],
   "stadium": [
     {
       "value":"Parce de france",
       "countries": ["France", "USA", "Canada"]}
   ]
 }
 {
   "city": "Roma",
   "arena": [
     {
       "value":"La cigal",
       "countries": ["France", "Itlay", "Spain"]
     }
   ],
   "stadium": [
     {
       "value":"Olymico",
       "countries": ["France"]
     }
   ]
 }
]
```

I was able to group by city with reduce

```
let group = function(array, key) {
  return array.reduce(function(result, item) {
    (result[item[key]] = result[item[key]] || []).push(item);
    return result;
  }, {});
};
```

How can I group the data first by city and then by stadium, including any arenas if they exist?

Answer (score 0):

The required output format is a little strange, but you can indeed do it with a single `reduce()` statement:

```js
const data = [{
  "countries": ["France", "USA", "Canada"],
  "city": "Paris",
  "stadium": "Parce de france"
}, {
  "countries": ["France", "Itlay", "Spain"],
  "city": "Roma",
  "arena": "La cigal"
}, {
  "countries": ["France"],
  "city": "Roma",
  "stadium": "Olymico"
}, {
  "countries": ["France"],
  "city": "Paris",
  "arena": "Velodrome"
}];

const result = Object.values(
  data.reduce((a, {city, arena, stadium, countries}) => {
    a[city] ??= { city, arena: [], stadium: [] };
    if (arena) a[city].arena.push({ value: arena, countries });
    if (stadium) a[city].stadium.push({ value: stadium, countries });
    return a;
  }, {})
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use map to transform each item in the data array into an object with the city, arena, and stadium. Later use reduce to group items by city and use spread operator to merge the arena and stadium data into arrays. In the end use Object.values() to get array of grouped objects:

```js
const data = [
 {
   "countries": ["France", "USA", "Canada"],
   "city": "Paris",
   "stadium": "Parce de france"
 },
 {
   "countries": ["France", "Itlay", "Spain"],
   "city": "Roma",
   "arena": "La cigal"
 },
  {
   "countries": ["France"],
   "city": "Roma",
   "stadium": "Olymico"
 },
 {
   "countries": ["France"],
   "city": "Paris",
   "arena": "Velodrome"
 },
]

const groupByCity = (array) =>
  Object.values(
array
  .map(({ city, stadium, arena, countries }) => ({
    city,
    arena: arena ? [{ value: arena, countries }] : [],
    stadium: stadium ? [{ value: stadium, countries }] : [],
  }))
  .reduce((result, { city, arena, stadium }) => {
    result[city] = result[city] || { city, arena: [], stadium: [] };
    result[city].arena = [...result[city].arena, ...arena];
    result[city].stadium = [...result[city].stadium, ...stadium];
    return result;
  }, {})
  );

const result = groupByCity(data);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using loadash for such computations it will make it easy

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy

```
HTML
<scriptsrc="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>


js
console.log(_.groupBy(_.groupBy(_.groupBy(data,'arena'),'stadium'),'city'));
```